# Does Azure offer free test credits to test a Mobile service?

Tags: azure, mobile, parse-platform, azure-mobile-services

I'm developing an app with a mobile backend. I've thought of using Azure. How am I supposed to test run the service? do they offer dev/free credits? I know Parse offers this facility. They offer 30 API calls per second for testing.

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Mobile Service Pricing - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/mobile-services/? They do offer a free tier.

Comment: If you have a msdn license they offer a certain amount of azure credits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test Mobile Services for free with these options:

When you create a new Azure account, you get over $200 of free credits to test the various services.  Note that these credits must be spent during the first month. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

Mobile Services has a free tier plan: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/mobile-services/

Are you working for a startup?  Check the BizSpark program that includes free Azure credits: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/bizspark-startups/

Are you a student?  Check the DreamSpark program that includes free Azure credits: https://www.dreamspark.com/

Are you an MSDN subscriber? Then you have free Azure credits: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits/

You can try Mobile App for free without creating an Azure account.  The caveat?  Your service will last only an hour ;-)  https://tryappservice.azure.com/

Comment: Thank you! info helped a lot.